# How to "Round half to Even"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I need to "Round half to Even" ([Bankers' rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)) a number in Excel. So:

```
4961,25 => 4961
9738,75 => 9739
4934,5 => 4934
4935,5 => 4936
```

How can I do it? It must also work "online", using Google Sheets (here is a [ready sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YN5axU45_rGXSA3pN9j3zos3ArYx6jOmYcaatUzcJZk/edit?usp=sharing)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This formula implements the equation from Wikipedia:

= -CEILING(-a_value - 0.5, 1) - 1 + ABS(SIGN(MOD(a_value, 2) - 0.5))

It works in Excel and Google Sheets. The spaces are optional.

Comment: It gives to me #ERROR# : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YN5axU45_rGXSA3pN9j3zos3ArYx6jOmYcaatUzcJZk/edit#gid=0

Comment: I see this is due to the locale settings (Italian?) of your Google Sheet. Replace periods with commas and commas with semicolons in the formula above. I copied the adapted formula to your sheet.

Answer (score 2):

> = -CEILING(-a_value - 0.5, 1) - 1 + ABS(SIGN(MOD(a_value, 2) - 0.5))

Sometimes does't works because even if you see 0.00 value, in fact it could be something like 8,88E-16 so SIGN() function return non zero value and CEILING() works not correct.

This one solve the problem:

= -CEILING(-round(value,12) - 0.5, 1) - 1 + ABS(SIGN(MOD(round(value,12), 2) - 0.5))

And here is ROUND_HALF_EVEN(value, 2) implementation:

= -CEILING(-round(value,12) - 0.005, 0.01) - 0.01 + ABS(SIGN(MOD(round(value*100,12), 2) - 0.5))*0.01